# Transparent is wrong under Android Pie

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, android-bitmap

i have at the moment a problem with the transparency of images under Android Pie.

It looks more white then transparent (look at the image)

The color settings in the bitmap config are ARGB_8888 every system under Pie works perfectly. Is this a general problem under Pie or is there a new settings for transparency in Pie for bitmaps?

[image: transparency more white then transparent]

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem? I have exactly the same one.

Comment: No, but I found a workaround. I only changed the transparency of the canvas layer to 0.2 for Pie devices

Comment: Thanks, will try it also.